# Access variable within a nested class in Python

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm having trouble with exactly what the title says. I have this code at one point:

```
class eventAdd:
    def __init__(self):
        class agendaEvent:
            def __init__(self, master):
                self.frame = Frame(master, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Later on, outside of the class eventAdd, but on the same level as eventAdd, I have:

```
def addEvent():
    instance = eventAdd()
    doneButton = Button([PROBLEM AREA], text="Done", command=done)
```

Where I have typed [PROBLEM AREA] is, quite obviously, the problem area. I want to create doneButton inside the frame inside agendaEvent inside eventAdd. Is it possible to reference a variable inside an init inside a class inside an init inside a class for use like this? If so, how?

I apologize for any programming sins I may have committed. I am fairly new to programming and I am not yet sure what the best way to go about things are. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Full Script:

```
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial


class eventAdd:
    def __init__(self):
        class agendaEvent:
            def __init__(self, master):
                self.frame = Frame(master, padx=10, pady=10)
                self.frame.grid()
                self.name = Entry(self.frame)
                self.name.grid(row=1, column=0)
                self.time = Entry(self.frame, width=10)
                self.time.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)
                self.label1 = Label(self.frame, text="Event Name")
                self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
                self.label2 = Label(self.frame, text="Minutes")
                self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1)



        def addOne(master):
            this_instance = agendaEvent(master)
            rem = Button(this_instance.frame, text="Remove", bg="lightblue",
                 command=partial(remove_class, this_instance))
            rem.grid(row=1, column=3)


        def remove_class(instance):
            instance.frame.destroy()
            instance = ""

        def done():
            print('tbd')

        window = Tk()

        addOneButton = Button(window, text="+1", command=partial(addOne, window))
        addOneButton.grid(row=1, column=0)

        window.mainloop()

def addEvent():
    instance = eventAdd()
    doneButton = Button([PROBLEM AREA], text="Done", command=done)
    doneButton.pack()

def done():
    print('tbd')

root = Tk()

addEventButton = Button(root, text="Add Events", command=addEvent)
addEventButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: Error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/John Grady/PycharmProjects/Dad's Agenda/scripts/main.py", line 41, in addEvent
    instance = agendaEvent(window)
  File "C:/Users/John Grady/PycharmProjects/Dad's Agenda/scripts/main.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.frame = Frame(master, padx=10, pady=10)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2565, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2086, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
TclError: can't invoke "frame" command:  application has been destroyed
```

Comment: Why are you declaring a class inside `__init__`? What do you expect that to do?

Comment: Using [global variable](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-you-set-a-global-variable-in-a-function.htm) may help you.

Comment: @JunYoungGwak Please, no.

Comment: @user2357112 inside the __init__ of eventAdd there are other functions that have been defined that effect the class agendaEvent.

Comment: @JohnHall: And why are *those* inside `__init__`? Are you sure it wouldn't be better to define this stuff outside of `__init__`, probably outside `eventAdd` entirely, and just pass appropriate arguments to `agendaEvent` instead?

Comment: @user2357112 maybe I should post the full script so you can see what I am talking about. I will edit the post.

Comment: @user2357112 I have added the full script to the post. Again, I am new to coding, so there may very well be a better way to do what I have done and I would love to hear about it if there is.

Comment: Just... put all that stuff outside `__init__`? I'm still not seeing why you defined any of those functions and classes inside `__init__`.

Comment: @user2357112 so I should keep them inside the class but not inside the __init__?

Comment: Outside the class entirely.

Comment: @user2357112 I removed everything from the class and almost everything worked the same. The +1 and Remove buttons work just fine. I have played around with it a bit but no matter what I do when I click the Add Events button, instead of opening up a new window with the agendaEvent class inside, it throws an error (will edit into post). I understand what I have now shouldn't open a window, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make a new window open without putting all of those things into a new class. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't see any value whatsoever in having a nested class. It only adds to the confusion and complexity. What's the real problem you're trying to solve? Finding a solution to code that is fundamentally incorrect isn't going to be very useful.

Comment: @BryanOakley If you run the initial full script I posted, you can get a sense of the original idea. I want to have one window with the "Add Events" button. Eventually, this will contain a master list of all the events that have been added, but until I get basic functionality, I will not add that. When I click the "Add Events" button, I want a new window to open where I can click the +1 button to add 1 to the amount of events I am adding, and for each event I want to put in the name and amount of time for the event. Again, I am not very good, and if there is a better solution, I would love to

Comment: hear it. I need more letters.

Comment: Also, I was unclear when I said "Is this possible?" earlier. I did not mean is the nested class idea possible because it was already way too convoluted for me. I was asking is it possible to do what I want without the nested class.

Comment: @John Hall Well, I was just suggesting a possibility. I knew this is not the right answer and that's why I commented.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish. Regardless, one problem you are going to have is that you should not be calling `Tk()` more than once, and you should only ever call `mainloop()` exactly once.

If you need multiple windows then you need to create instances of `Toplevel`. Any solution which requires destroying and recreating a root window is going to be hard to get right.

Comment: I will look into top Toplevel. Thanks for the heads up.